# Asking company X a question throws an exception

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

If you are looking to apply to a job there is a link to "Ask X a question" as shown:

[image]

By clicking on this link a popup appears allowing you to ask a question.  If you click **Send Message** the system dies:

[image]

Couple things missing here, there is no validation on the message hence the exception.  Can we please jquery this.

Comment: Repro'd, thanks. To clarify this occurs with an empty message.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed - thanks for the report.

Comment: I'll check this tomorrow